# VBA, tring to find a word, from a range, using a user defined function

Tags: vba, user-defined-functions

if I have a list of important words, and then a text/comment field.
I'm wanting to search the field, for any of the important words (whole words, not just strings)

i.e. If important word is "cat", I don't want "category" or "scatman" to return a positive.

Here is the function so far

```
Function RangeFunc(rng As Range, funct As String) As String
Dim c As Range
Dim cnt As Integer
cnt = 0

For Each c In rng.Cells
    'If c.Text = funct Then
    If InStr(c.Text, " "&funct&" ") > 0 Then

        cnt = cnt + 1

    End If
Next c
RangeFunc = cnt
```

End Function

IT doesn't seem to be returning single word counts

Comment: the function `InStr`is used to find a string inside another, so if you are looking for Cat it will throw you a match on Scatman. You might want to use the `Find` which has a property `LookAt:=xlWhole` meaning it will only look for the exact word.

Comment: You could say `if len(funct)<>len(replace(funct,c.text,vbnullstring))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using two ranges, one for the list checking and one for the items to look for, so having the list to check in A1:A3 and the checking list in C1:C3, I used

`=SUM(--($A$1:$A$3=$C$1:$C$3))`

This is an array formula, so requires, ctrl shift and enter to enter it into a cell.

You could do

`application.Evaluate("=SUM(--($A$1:$A$3=$C$1:$C$3))")`

in VBA off this instead.

Comment: Thanks, am i able to use it, with list to single cell.
i.e. =sum(--(A1:A3=C1))
?

Comment: That's `SUMIF` :o)